# XSLT matching and sorting with external list stored in XML file

Tags: xslt, filter

Hi all StackOverFlowers,

I am stumbled upon a big non-solvable problem, trying to sort my XML. I have XML data set formulated like below;

```
<root>
  <node code="text1"> ... </node>
  <node code="text2"> ... </node>
  <node code="text3"> ... </node>
  <node code="textX"> ... </node>
</root>
```

Now i want to sort it by code attribute and would like to store a list of code attributes sorted in external file SORT.XML. Code attributes would be sorted and saved in SORT.XML something like this (one line, one attribute);

```
textX
text2
text1
text3
```

... and so on...

Once processed and OUTPUT.XML would look like;

```
<root>
  <node code="textX"> ... </node>
  <node code="text2"> ... </node>
  <node code="text1"> ... </node>
  <node code="text3"> ... </node>
</root>
```

I am really stuck, and don't have any clue how to continue/solve this with XSLT?

Thanks for all your help!

DeLuka

Comment: I am not sure I understand this. It seems more like a grouping problem than a sorting one. What should happen to values not listed in the given sort order? -- P.S. Please indicate if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0/3.0.

Comment: Values not in XML would simply be skipped.

Comment: Which XML? Please adjust your example to be clear. -- Note also that your SORT.XML is not XML, the way you show it.

Comment: It's not solving it the way you ask, but you can maybe use `grep -f sortfile input.xml` to get your nodes in the correct order, and you'd just need to stick your root element on the top and bottom of that.

Comment: Sorry for that - it is true it is not XML. What i meant is, that i would like to load data from external file like showed above.

Comment: @cmbuckley what a horrible suggestion, unless you want the recipients of your efforts to join the ranks of SO posters asking "How do I deal with ill-formed XML?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are required to use the "one line per code" file format that you described, then parsing the codes is a bit tricky in XSLT 1. It's relatively straightforward in XSLT 2. Just include the file and use the `tokenize` function:

Note: if there are markup characters in your codes like `<` and `&` you will need to escape them.

```
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet [
    <!ENTITY codes SYSTEM "sort.txt">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:sort="urn:sort">
    <!-- Include the ordered list of codes. -->
    <sort:order>&codes;</sort:order>

    <!-- This key is used to select the nodes to output -->
    <xsl:key name="node-key" match="node" use="@code"/>

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="root" select="."/>
            <!-- For each code in the list, output the nodes with matching code attributes -->
            <xsl:for-each select="tokenize(document('')/*/sort:order, '\s+')">
                <xsl:copy-of select="key('node-key', ., $root)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Tokenising strings in XSLT 1 is ugly, but if you format your list of codes as XML then you won't have to.

With your codes formatted like this:

```
<codes>
    <code>textX</code>
    <code>text2</code>
    <code>text1</code>
    <code>text3</code>
</codes>
```

You can run the sort in XSLT 1:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="root" select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="document('sort.xml')/codes/code">
                <xsl:copy-of select="$root/node[@code=current()]"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```